# composite partition key - row searching VS. column searching

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

My query is to get the score of a particular student for a particular exam. For the Cassandra table design, Option 1,

```
 CREATE TABLE student_score (
  student_name text,
  exam_name text,
  score int,
  exam_time timeuuid
  PRIMARY KEY (exam_name,student_name)
 )
 WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (student_name DESC);
```

exam_name will be the partition key, and all students will be in the wide row.

Option 2,

```
 CREATE TABLE student_score (
  student_name text,
  exam_name text,
  score int,
  exam_time timeuuid
  PRIMARY KEY ((exam_name,student_name))
 )
```

exam_name and student_name together form the partition key, so there is no wide row.

Option 1 is the standard way. But what is wrong with option 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with option 2, but with option 2 you will only able to query using exam_name and student_name together.

Option one will face issue in data distribution if more students appear for particular exam,i.e data will not be evenly distributed.

Both approach will face issue if multiple student's with same name appear for same exam.

Comment: Tks. The assumption is the uniqueness of the student name. Yes, option 1 will hv hotspot issue potentially. Besides the query's where clause difference, any pros and cons ? Like storage, query speed etc.

Comment: yes query speed will definitely increase, because data will not have to be filtered out as in case of option 1. Option 2 will create structure something similar to rows of RDMS